# Alarm not rang in specific time android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Here is my code

when i set alarm and restart my phone after that alarm not working

**Example**
i set alarm 4pm

some how i restart my phone at 3pm

that alarm rang in 3pm

not 4pm

Boot_receiver

```
public class Boot_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SettingswithSliding aw=new SettingswithSliding();
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
    //  aw.setAlarm(8, null);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Notification_Quote.class);

        try {
            MyBaseClass.editor_base = MyBaseClass.preferences_base.edit();
            MyBaseClass.editor_base.putInt("Restarted", 1);
            MyBaseClass.editor_base.commit();


            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            /*calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);*/
            Log.d("sdfn", "djfgv"+calendar);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, 0, i, 0);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent); // set repeating every 24 hours
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getMessage() != null) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }else
    {
        Log.d("ram", "e");
    }
}}
```

Notification_quote

```
public class Notification_Quote extends BroadcastReceiver {

NotificationManager nm;
String Quotename;
Long li;
Intent intent;
int Quote_id, flag;
Long l_time;
Cursor getQuote = null;
DatabaseHelper helper;
static int pi_id = 0;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context
                        .getApplicationContext());
        l_time = pref.getLong("calendar_value", 0);
        try {
            helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            helper.createDatabase();
            helper.openDataBase();
            getQuote = helper.getRandomQuote(1, "");

            if (getQuote != null) {
                getQuote.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    Quote_id = getQuote.getInt(0);
                    Quotename = getQuote.getString(1).toString();

                } while (getQuote.moveToNext());
            }
            getQuote.close();

        } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
            if (ne.getMessage() != null) {
                Log.e("ERROR", ne.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            if (se.getMessage() != null) {
                Log.e("ERROR", se.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getMessage() != null) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                helper.close();
            } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
                if (ne.getMessage() != null) {
                    Log.e("null pointer ERROR", ne.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e.getMessage() != null) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

    nm = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence from = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    CharSequence message = Quotename;
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Single_Quote.class);
    Bundle bnd = new Bundle();
    bnd.putInt(context.getString(R.string.package_name) + ".quote_day", 3);
    Log.d("fe", "" + context.getString(R.string.package_name)
            + ".quote_day");
    i.putExtras(bnd);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            ++pi_id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("Qid", Quote_id); // value to store
    editor.commit();

/*  SettingswithSliding sw=new SettingswithSliding();
    sw.setAlarm(8,contentIntent );*/


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
//  long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
Log.d("tome", ""+calendar+time1);


    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, message,
            time1);
     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SettingswithSliding.class);
     PendingIntent pie = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent , 0);
    Log.d("d", ""+notif);
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, pie);
    notif.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
    notif.ledOnMS = 2000;
    notif.ledOffMS = 1000;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE
            | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;




    long[] vibrate = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
    notif.vibrate = vibrate;
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/"
            + R.raw.notification);
    notif.sound = sound;
    nm.notify(1, notif);

}}
```

Here is my code

When my phone is reboot that alarm is not working in specific time

Here my menifiest

```
    <receiver android:name=".Boot_Receiver"
        android:enabled="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Please some help me....